# Use if statement to check if value in DB table is unique with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, if-statement, unique

I'd like to use an if statement to check if the value in a Postgres DB table is unique. If unique, then do something, if not unique, do something else. Here's what the pseudo code would look like in Ruby on Rails.

```
if validates_uniqueness_of :number == "true"
    puts "this value is unique and should be added to the DB"
else 
    puts "this value is not unique and should not be added to the DB"
end
```

Can this type of logic be implemented in the model or controller? If yes, which is the better way to go? If no, what should I do instead? Also, what would the syntax look for something like this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) method to check whether a record is in the database already. It can take a hash of fields you want to search on:

```
before_create :do_something_if_unique

def do_something_if_unique
  if self.class.exists?(number: number)
    # there is a record that exists with this number
  else
    # there are no records that exist with this number
  end
end
```

Comment: This is almost working, thanks! In the case there is no record, the code is executing correctly which is great. Though, in the case there is a record that exists with a particular value, that code isn't executing correctly.  Also, so you mind explaining what this means '(number: number)' ?

Comment: (number: number) is a hash - Ruby 1.9 syntax. I wrote that as an example of what you can do with `exists?` but you might need to tweak it to match your exact use case. number would be whatever field you are trying to validate the uniqueness of. In this case, it would see if any records exist that have a "number" that matches whatever you've set that value to on the model.

Comment: No prob. I do want to point out that if your application is write heavy (ie lots of records being created), you may run into an issue where the query is run to check if one already exists, and by the time it writes to it, another process has already inserted a record that would cause the original query to return true. You may want to use database constraints to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

In order to found unique values in a column, I'd do something like:

```
def self.has_unique_numbers?
    pluck(:number).uniq.count == 1
end
```

Then in your model or controller, you can ask:

```
if YourModel.has_unique_numbers?
    # Some Code
else
    # Some other code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first_or_create`:

```
MyModel.where(number: number).first_or_create!
```

If nothing is found matching the given criteria (more AR methods can be chained in as well), the object is saved to the database. Whether it should go in the model or controller depends on how you are using it. It should work fine in either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `:validates_uniqueness_of` for model validations.  Whether or not you want to additionally add database constraints is a bigger issue open to a lot of debate depending on what side of the fence you sit on :)

```
class MyThing < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :number, :uniqueness => true
end

a = MyThing.create(:number => 1) # will succeeed
b = MyThing.create(:number => 2) # will fail and a.errors will contain more info.
```